# Log user into facebook using session key from my Facebook app

Tags: java, authentication, facebook, java-me

I have a simple Desktop Facebook application that allows the user to retrieve some of their Facebook info(Written in Java). This info is then sent to their phone.

When the user sees something of interest (e.g. new comment) in their phone's 'facebook-viewer' (JavaME) they can click to launch a browser and go to 'facebook.com' to view it.

Is there a way to get a pre-authenticated URL to send to the phone (using the session-key aquired on the Desktop) so that they don't have to 'log-in' to their phone's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I've read - it looks like this functionality is available in a private API, but for normal people, it is as 'plafayette' says: not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, the user must login on the mobile app as well. Using a mobile Facebook application is no different than using your Desktop application on another machine. The login must occur for security reasons. If you could pass around pre-authenticated URLs this would be a major security issue as URLs are easy to steal. See [mobile authentication](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorization_and_Authentication_for_Facebook_for_Mobile_Applications).